# Using promises in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, spotify, angular-promise

I am writing an application that connects with Spotify's API. Here is the basic flow of what I am trying to do.

1. The user types in an artist and I get the artists' spotify id.
2. I use that id to find the related artists.
3. I store the top tracks of each of those related artists.
4. I create a playlist with those songs for a specific user.

Now, this obviously needs to happen in a specific order (I think the term is synchronously). I've only just learned about Promises today, and I'm not very sure about how to use them. I believe that it is a way to chain functions together to ensure that they happen in a specific order. However, I do not know how to actually do that.

Here is what I have tried to do to attempt it:

```
angular.module('smart-spot', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', [
        '$scope', '$http',
        function($scope, $http)
        {
            $scope.createPlaylist = function()
            {
                var artist = $scope.artist;
                console.log(artist);
                window.open("/login", "Playlist Creation", 'WIDTH=400, HEIGHT=500');
                var artistId;
                getArtistId(artist)
                    .then(function(response) //this is where the below error is referring to
                    {
                        artistId = response.data;
                        getRelatedArtists(artistId)
                            .then(function(response)
                            {
                                //this chaining doesn't appear to be working.
                            }, function(error)
                            {
                                return $q.reject(error);
                            })
                    }, function(error)
                    {
                        return $q.reject(error);
                    });
            };
            var getArtistId = function(artist)
            {
                $http.get('/search', { params:{ artist:artist } })
                    .then(function(response)
                    {
                        console.log(response);
                        return response;
                    }, function(error)
                    {
                        return $q.reject(error);
                    });
            };

            var getRelatedArtists = function(artist)
            {
                //get the related artists
            }
        }
    ]);
```

I get an error in the console tough that says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` on the line marked above. So, trying to chain these functions together doesn't work like I want it to.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getArtistId` is not returning a promise object, since it is using `ajax`, you can return the same promise returned by the `$http.get()` call

```
$scope.createPlaylist = function() {
  var artist = $scope.artist;
  console.log(artist);
  window.open("/login", "Playlist Creation", 'WIDTH=400, HEIGHT=500');
  var artistId;
  getArtistId(artist)
    .then(function(response) //this is where the below error is referring to
      {
        artistId = response.data;
        //same way getRelatedArtists has to return a promise
        getRelatedArtists(artistId)
          .then(function(response) {
          }, function(error) {
            //handle the error if you want to
          })
      },
      function(error) {
        //no need to return anything here, if you want to display an error message to the user you can do that here
      });
};
var getArtistId = function(artist) {
  return $http.get('/search', {
    params: {
      artist: artist
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the statement `return $q.reject(error);`? I've seen it in various places, but you're saying it's not necessary. When would it be necessary?

Comment: @CacheStaheli not in this case as you are not chaining the `then` further, but if you want to use then promise returned by `then` further then you need to do that